# Hi! How to make this simple? Im new to python :)

Tags: python

i have a code like this

```
if res == 'A':
        A += 1
    elif res == 'B':
        B += 1
    elif res == 'C':
        C += 1
    elif res == 'D':
        D += 1
    elif res == 'E':
        E += 1
    elif res == 'G':
        G += 1
```

how to simplify it? Thank u :)

Comment: Use dictionaries instead. Then you can do `my_dict[res]+=1` avoiding long `if-elif` ladder.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this solution aligned with Ch3steR.

```
my_dict = {key:0 for key in 'ABCDEG'}

res: str = "A"
my_dict[res] +=1
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: You can do `my_dict=dict.fromkeys('ABCDE',0)` instead of `{key:0 for key in 'ABCDEG'}` +1. Thanks for the creds.

Comment: Note: NSR's way is not the way you should consider using this.

Comment: okay i see thank you for helping. I will try it. Stay safe and hv a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

consider using a dictionary like this:

```
data = {  'A':A,
      'B':B,
      'C':C,
      'D':D,
      'E':E,  }

data[res]+=1
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it. Hv a nice day! Stay safe :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
data = {'A':A, 'B':B, 'C':C, 'D':D, 'E':E}

if res in data.keys():  # to check consistency
    data[res] += 1
```